# Different settings.py file for different domains in Django

Tags: python, django, aws-lambda, wsgi, zappa

I have a Django project that will have multiple instances, one for each of my clients, each instance have your own DB and some custom APPs and your own domain, but all share the same source code, the only difference will be the settings.py file pointing for the correct DB.

I know I can achieve this using different virtual hosts pointing to different settings using for exemple Apache and WSGI, but in my case I will use AWS Lambda and Zappa to provide this service for my clients.

I want to know if exists a way to dynamically load some custom settings depending on the domain that loads the site.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that you are going to have multiple instances, I'm guessing that that means *one client=one lambda*.
You can use Zappa's feature to deploy to several environments with one main zappa config that you are going to extend.
In each deplyment environment you can set specific django settings file to be used.

#### zappa_settings.json

```
{
    "common": {
        "aws_region": "eu-central-1",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "project_name": "zappa3",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-ewdnqwii5"
    },
    "client_1": {
        "extends": "common",
        "django_settings": "zappa3.settings.client_1",
        "domain": "client-1.com"
    },
    "client_2": {
        "extends": "common",
        "django_settings": "zappa3.settings.client_1",
        "domain": "client-2.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Humm, interesting aproach, I will tale a look, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the `extends` key, it is a little hidden in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert settings.py to settings folder and create as many domain's setting you would like to add. I would create base.py for common setting and then each domain which has a specific setting should import base.py and additional domain specific settings.

Directory structure would be:

- settings:

  - base.py
  - domain_1.py
  - domain_2.py
  - ...

When you load domain_1 then try to load using `python manage.py runserver --settings=settings.domain_1.py` and `request.meta['HTTP_HOST']` can give you domain name.

Comment: Ok, this I know, but how I will detect the domain dynamically and make this command execute with the right domain?